# Java: Using Scanner to add item in method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm having issues with finding the right order to so my program will work. It's probably quite easy but I'm very new to programming so hope someone can help me!

From a file I get input which needs to be read line by line. I have 4 items on the line which need to be read and put into action. I've use the scanner to read the file line by line and then each item. But then when I want to call to items the program doesn't do anything. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Example of the input:

black   32  move c 4

black   0   move d 4

white   4198    move c 3

```
    void start() {

Scanner fileScanner = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();    

    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) { 
        fileScanner.next();

        String inputPlayer = fileScanner.next();

        int thinkingTime = fileScanner.nextInt();

        String inputMoveOrPass = fileScanner.next();

        char inputHorizontalCoordinate = fileScanner.next().charAt(0);
        int x = inputHorizontalCoordinate - 97;

        int inputVerticalCoordinate = fileScanner.nextInt();
        int y = inputVerticalCoordinate - 1;



        ui.wait(thinkingTime);

        if (inputPlayer.equals("white")) {
            ui.place(x, y, ui.WHITE);
            }
        else if (inputPlayer.equals("black")) {
            ui.place(x, y, ui.BLACK);
        }

        ui.showChanges();



        }

    }
```

Comment: `next()` returns the current item and pushes the internal iterator by 1. When you continously call `next`, without checking if there even is a next via `hasNext`, you run the risk of `null pointer exceptions`

Comment: @Frontear if a `Scanner` reaches the end of an input and attempts to read something, it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`, not a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The fact that your code does nothing is rather peculiar. Given your input and your code, I would expect a `NoSuchElementException` to be thrown. Perhaps the exception is being caught and you don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to read a `String` from each line of the file before beginning to read input, which doesn't seem to be aligned with what you want to do. Delete or comment out the first call to `fileScanner.next()` might do the trick.
i.e.

```java
Scanner fileScanner = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();

while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    // fileScanner.next();

    String inputPlayer = fileScanner.next();

    int thinkingTime = fileScanner.nextInt();
```